# Alinhamento vertical de texto com CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: screenshot do texto desalinhado]

Como posso alinhar esse texto "Adote o ritmo da natureza: o segredo dela é a paciência", verticalmente e horizontalmente dentro do campo branco?

Usei o seguinte código:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a>
       adote o ritmo da natuza: o segredo dela é a paciência.
     </a>
     <h2>Ralph Waldo Emerson</h2>
  </li>
<li>
```

```css
ul{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    position: relative;
    width: 309px;
    height: 260px;
    background: #f3f2f1;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 19px 19px 0;

}
ul li  a{
    width: 257px;
    height: 170px;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    color: #f37021;
    font-family: Futura;
    font-size: 15px;
}
 ul li h2{
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #111111;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 1. Alinhando o texto no meio da célula

Crie uma div com a classe `vertical` contendo o texto. Depois use:

```
.vertical {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

## 2. Rotacionando o Texto

Crie uma div com a classe `vertical` contendo o texto. Depois use:

```
.vertical {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* opcional: Opera agora usa -webkit */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* opcional: Opera agora usa -webkit */
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  /* Use se você quer que apareça para o IE8. */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Comment: Cigano Morrison Mendez, na verdade o que eu preciso é alinhar verticalmente e horizontalmente no espaço branco.

Comment: Expandi a resposta.

Comment: Alguém já perguntou no meta sobre o que fazer com propriedades prefixadas? IMHO nunca uso: quem irá copiar nossos códigos - e tenha certeza que farão - irão usar prefixos que nunca serão necessários. Exemplo? `-o-`.

Comment: `-o-` é do Opera, não? Sei lá. Resolvi colocar um CSS completo.

Comment: `-ms-`: a Microsoft removeu grande parte dos prefixos. `-o-`: agora o Opera usa Webkit. Já falei por aqui do [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) mas recomendo o [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer), ainda mais para respostas.

Comment: Editei colocando suas observações. Vou deixar por desencargo.

Comment: Testei seu código no autoprefixer, nas opções padrão: ele deixou os prefixos `-ms-` e `-webkit-`. *Grande parte...*

Answer (score 0):

Porque não usar `line-height` ?

```
ul li{
    position: relative;
    width: 309px;
    height: 260px;
    background: #f3f2f1;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 19px 19px 0;
    line-height: 260px;
}
```

Para mim funciona bem.

Perdão pela gafe, não tinha visto que o texto possui espaçamento e que já tinha tentado o `line-height`.

Answer (score -1):

No seu caso, basta trocar de `display:block` para **`display: grid;`** e acrescentar o **`align-items: center;`** no `ul` `li` e `a`

```css
ul{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    position: relative;
    width: 309px;
    height: 260px;
    background: #f3f2f1;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 19px 19px 0;

}
ul li  a{
    width: 257px;
    height: 170px;
    background: #fff;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    color: #f37021;
    font-family: Futura;
    font-size: 15px;
}
 ul li h2{
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #111111;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a>
             adote o ritmo da natuza: o segredo dela é a paciência.
           </a>
           <h2>Ralph Waldo Emerson</h2>
        </li>
</body>
</html>
```